# Laptop won't turn on after bios flash

Tags: bios

I have a acer 4820tg was having problems with the video driver, the pc shout down while I was editing a photo in photoshop, turned it on I got a blue screen something about atikmpag.sys

I reintalled windows everything was working perfectly after the windows mandatory updates I got the atikmpag.sys again, after playing around with drivers with no luck I updated the bios to the latest version no problems, after a lot of tries to make the drivers work I went to the bios and switch the graphics from switchable to discrete  (I have to do this to boot mac os I thought this would help, I had no problems doing this on the previous bios version)after saving the settings the pc turns on but no post.

I tried flashing the bios again (yes before doing this i tried removing the internal battery didn't reset the bios settings) I pressed fn and esc after 10 min nothing happened I turned off my laptop but now it doesn't turn on I press the power button but nothing happens

Bios I tried (the original not the modded): http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/acer-aspire-timelinex-4820tg-5820tg-modded-bios-insyde.568951/

Comment: Sounds like you have bricked the device, instead of flashing the firmware multiple times, why didn't you just load the defaults?

Comment: Yes but I didn't knew how, I tried removing the internal battery to force the bios to default but didn't worked, I have programming and soldering skills  I already saw bios chips on sale but I don't know if this will fix it